# Разрешить отправку форм в сниппетах

Tags: поддержка, предложение, сниппеты

В сниппетах запрещена отправка форм, что мешает сделать работающий пример, в котором правильно используются формы (обработка отправки, а не клика по кнопке):

> Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Вот пример такого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635871/178988

Были ли какие-то причины так сделать, или же это просто недоработка?

Comment: скорее всего, просто настройки выкручены на максимум, типа - ничего нельзя

Comment: Подскажите, пробовали ли вы сделать тоже самое на SOen?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вроде там так же. По крайней мере, если в редакторе сниппетов проверять, то так же.

Comment: Там всё так же должно быть, сниппеты хостятся на отдельном домене, `stacksnippets.net`, чтобы избежать доступности сайтов SE согласно same origin policy. Пока что лучшее, что я нашёл на метах, это что этим избегается эксплуатация сниппетов для выполнения XSS на уязвимых сайтах. Но это выглядит как-то совсем слабо, код ведь можно где угодно разместить, сниппеты не дают преимуществ...